# execute and load controllers only after finishing a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've created an application angular js in which i'm having many number of controllers in a single page as shown below

```
app.controller('Controller1', function($rootScope, $scope)
{
    :
    :
});

app.controller('Controller2', function($rootScope, $scope)
{
    :
    :
});

app.controller('Controller3', function($rootScope, $scope)
{
    :
    :
});
```

I've a service which fetches user properties from the rest service. The application works fine but the problem is the before getting the datas from the service all the controllers are getting executed

can anyone tell me how to load all the controllers only after the service for getting the user properties is completely loaded finished, the service is given below

```
app.factory('userConfig', function($rootScope, appConfig, UserConfig)
{
    $rootScope.userConfig = UserConfig.get(function(data)
    {
        $rootScope.userConfig = _.clone(data.userproperties, true);
        :
        :
    });
});
```

My script is given below

```
var app = angular.module('app',[ 'commonServices']);

app.factory('userConfig', function($rootScope, appConfig, UserConfig)
{
    $rootScope.userConfig = UserConfig.get(function(data)
    {
        $rootScope.userConfig = _.clone(data.userproperties, true);
        :
        :
    });
});

app.controller('Controller1', function($rootScope, $scope)
{
    :
    :
});

app.controller('Controller2', function($rootScope, $scope)
{
    :
    :
});

app.controller('Controller3', function($rootScope, $scope)
{
    :
    :
});
```

Comment: The best solution is to eliminate the order of loading from being a problem. For example you could use some deferred/promises etc.

Comment: can you please show me one @ExpertSystem

Comment: Share some cde that illustrates why the loading order is a problem, so we can refactor it.

Comment: did'nt get you @ExpertSystem

Comment: In order to propose a way to solve the problem, I need to see it first (i.e. see how your controllers use your data and how this is a problem when they are loaded before the service).

Comment: see the thing is i'm having a select box in which all the properties is loaded. so after the services is executed only then the select is filled with datas. here in my application the page is loaded first with no values in select. after sometimes when the services is finished the datas are loaded within the select

Comment: Are you using `ngRoute` ?

Comment: So, what do you want to happen while your service is loading data ?

Comment: the ui should'nt display except the select.......

Comment: See Vladimir's answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the code that uses these controllers behind an ng-if that only gets enabled when some promise gets resolved.

factory:

```
app.factory('userConfig', function($rootScope, appConfig, UserConfig) {
    UserConfig.get(function(data) {
      $rootScope.userConfig = _.clone(data.userproperties, true);
    });
});
```

template:

```
<div ng-if="userConfig">
   <div ng-controller="Controller1">foo1</div>
   <div ng-controller="Controller2">foo2</div>
   <div ng-controller="Controller3">foo3</div>
</div>
```

Alternatively you can use ui-router 'resolve' attribute: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve

Comment: but we need to hard code things within UI using ng-if....can we control that within scipt without statically using ng-if in UI

Comment: using ng-if as well as any other ng-XX directives is pretty conventional in the AngularJS world of declarative programming. I would certainly not call it hardcoding.

Comment: p.s. just to be clear ng-if="userConfig" refers to an object on your scope(or $rootScope) that is null until it gets resolved from within UserConfig.get function/promise